# Play animation with animate.css when removing item

Tags: css, animation

I am using this CSS file http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ to add some animation to the web site I am building.
The thing is I need to play an animation when I delete an item from a list for example, but how can I do that since the element is no longer in the DOM?

Comment: Run the animations before you actually delete it?

Comment: Hi, I have already tried but it didn't work as expected. I explain:
I have a table with some rows, there is a confirmation prompt before deleting any item. If I do like you said, my animation will hide the row being deleted from the table before the user confirm. the element is still there but hidden

Comment: then fire the animation when the user clicks to confirm the delete.

Comment: or better yet, post some code.  We can't help without anything to go off of.

Answer (score 0):

All right, 
here is my jsp code:

```
<tbody class="filter">
    <c:forEach var="message" items="${messages}">
        <tr id="${message.id}" class="body">
            <td>${message.name}</td>
            <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${not empty message.file}"><td>${message.file.name}</td></c:when>
            <c:otherwise><td>${message.tts}</td></c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        <td class="icon"><i id="delete" class="icon-trash icon-hover"></i></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

And some jQuery:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "message/delete/" + id,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        if (response.status == "OK") {
        $row.addClass('animated flipOutX');
                // Here I need to run an animation before I delete the item.
        $('#messageTable tr#' + id).remove();
        }
    }
 });
```

Thank you again for your help!

**UPDATE:**

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/g3WLM/1/

Comment: I found the solution. I need to detect whe the animation ends, and then remove the row:

`$row.addClass('animated flipOutX').one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e) {
              $(this).remove();
     });`